# Trigger and function to insert user id into another table

Tags: postgresql, identifier, case-sensitive, prisma, supabase

I am using Prisma as my schema and migrating it to supabase with `prisma migrate dev`

One of my tables Profiles, should reference the auth.users table in supabase, in sql something like this `id uuid references auth.users not null,`

Now since that table is automatically created in supabase do I still add it to my prisma schema? It's not in public either it is in auth.

```
model Profiles {
  id               String   @id @db.Uuid
  role             String
  subId            String
  stripeCustomerId String
  refundId         String[]
  createdAt        DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt        DateTime @updatedAt
}
```

The reason I want the relation is because I want a trigger to automatically run  a function that inserts an id and role into the profiles table when a new users is invited.

This is that trigger and function

```
-- inserts a row into public.profiles
create function public.handle_new_user() 
returns trigger 
language plpgsql 
security definer 
as $$
begin
  insert into public.Profiles (id, role)
  values (new.id, 'BASE_USER');
  return new;
end;
$$;

-- trigger the function every time a user is created
create trigger on_auth_user_created
  after insert on auth.users
  for each row execute procedure public.handle_new_user();
```

I had this working when I created the profiles table manually in supabase I included the reference to the `auth.users`, that's the only reason I can think of why the user Id and role won't insert into the profiles db when I invite a user, the trigger and function are failing

```
create table public.Profiles (
  id uuid references auth.users not null,
  role text,

  primary key (id)
);
```

Update from comment:
One error I found is

> ```
> relation "public.profiles" does not exist
> ```

I change it to `"public.Profiles"` with a capital in supabase, but the function seem to still be looking for lowercase.

Comment: *Always* disclose the Postgres version in use. `SELECT version();`. And the verbatim error message! And the *exact* table definition, most importantly the *exact* FK definition. *"Something like"* is not good enough. I guess it's about foreign key violation ...

Comment: PostGresSQL, I can't seem to find the exact error in the database logs. I will search for a foreign key error. Update: I dont see a foreign key violation error. I am just not sure where to find the error in the logs, I just got a feed back UI error in supabase saying user creation failed, but when I deleted the function and trigger the create user worked fine, and when I created the profiles table with sql command it worked with the trigger and function it's when I created the profiles table with prisma that the trigger and function no longer work

Comment: [No such thing as "PostGresSQL".](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Identity_Guidelines) I am asking for [your *version* of Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). And try harder to find the all-important error message.

Comment: this is the output of the command in the SQL editor SELECT version();
PostgreSQL 14.1 on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) 10.3.0, 64-bit

Comment: One error I found is `relation "public.profiles" does not exist` I change it to "public.Profiles" with a capital in supabase, but the function seem to still be looking for lowercase. I will try and recreate the function and trigger with a capital and see

Comment: Did you create your table as `"Profiles"` or as `Profiles`? See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20880247/939860

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you show should just work:

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=8f64ca37e384ae33db0550e279311b74)*

Looks like you messed up capitalization with Postgres identifiers.

If you (or your ORM) created the table as `"Profiles"` (with double-quotes), non-standard capitalization is preserved and you need to double-quote the name for the rest of its life.

So the trigger function body must read:

```
...
insert into public."Profiles" (id, role)  -- with double-quotes
...
```

Note that schema and table (and column) have to be quoted *separately*.

See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)